# pip install git+url within a docker environment

Tags: python, docker, pip

I am using this Docker (FROM lambci/lambda:python3.6) and I need to install a private repository package. The problem is the Docker does not have git and I can not install git using apt-get or apk install because the Docker is not Linux.

Is there any possible way to fix this installing git? Or is there any other better method I could use to install this private repository package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add this to makefile:

```
# makefile
git clone REPO
cd REPO_DIR; python setup.py bdist_wheel
cp REPO_DIR/dist/* .
rm -rf REPO_DIR/
```

add this to dockerfile:

```
# dockerfile
RUN pip install REPO*.whl
```

and then the package is successfully installed within docker

Comment: Could you explain why the simple pip install-e command does not work and that we need to do all the manual job ? :)

Answer (score 7):

```
RUN python -m pip install git+URL_OF_GIT_REPO
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: The problem is the Docker does not have git and I can not install git using apt-get or apk install because the Docker is not Linux

Answer (score 2):

in your dockerfile put this code before installing requirements and you will be fine:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
```

Answer (score 2):

```
FROM python:3.9 as builder
RUN pip install --target /tmp/site-packages "git+GIT_URL"

FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9
COPY --from=builder /tmp/site-packages /var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

You could use python:3.9 which has git, or any other image to install dependancies and then copy it into the AWS image.

To find the site-packages location, just use `python -m site` in a lambda container

Answer (score 0):

can you `pip install` the git repo next to your source code and mount it together with your code into the container?

```
cd WORKING_DIRECTORY
pip install --target ./ GIT_URL
```

Comment: I am basically using this repo (github.com/21Buttons/pychromeless), to do this you are suggesting I would have to `pip install --target ./src GIT_URL` ? And then the rest should work fine?

Comment: I tried to to this `pip install --target ./src GIT_URL` and it does not work. It can't find the dependencies of the repository when importing it. Is there any way to pip install into a file then using this file to later pip install using this file?

Comment: With `--target` you can tell python where to place the files it installs. Then you can mount them into your container yourself.