# Install python packages from github with Docker

Tags: python, docker, pip

I am trying to install a package that is not on PyPi. i.e from github. Adding the repo as git+url to the requirements file gives

```
ERROR: Error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'git' while executing command git clone -q https://github.com/Rapptz/discord-ext-menus /tmp/pip-req-build-147rct22
ERROR: Cannot find command 'git' - do you have 'git' installed and in your PATH?
```

Installing the packages is done with

```
RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

as specified in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/language/python/build-images/)

I also tried the solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55249689/pip-install-giturl-within-a-docker-environment), but the answers mess up my other packages.

The dockerfile is almost directly from the docs

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python3", "main.py"]
```

requirements.txt

```
asyncpg==0.21.0
git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord-ext-menus
discord.py==1.7.0
pre-commit==2.10.1
pyclean==2.0.0
pylint==2.6.0
python-dotenv==0.15.0
```

Comment: Show us you `Dockerfile` and `requirements.txt`!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error tells us, we have to simply install git, so that pip can clone the repo and run the setup file.
We can install git with

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
```

We also have to build from a python image, the above answer works with [python:3.8-slim-buster](https://github.com/docker-library/python/tree/cb9a39a6c48d4606a68ae8f986373c9c64d430b5/3.8/buster/slim)